# Hello, I intalled ocmod on opencart 3.0.2.0 but I get this error when trying to activate this extension

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, ocmod

need help

> Warning: checkdnsrr(): Host cannot be empty in
> /home/i2aufl9xb/public_html/demo/admin/controller/extension/analytics/open_search.php
> on line 218

Comment: Need more details. Can you update your question with the code form your ocmod?

Comment: this is the code of open_search.php

Comment: at line 218 :    if (!checkdnsrr($mail[1], "MX")) {
            $this->error['mail_contact'][$language_id] = $this->language->get('error_mail_contact');
           }

Comment: Can you open your OCMOD file, which you were installing, edit your question and post there your code form OCMOD?

Comment: The code is too long to post it here.

Comment: Not in comment. Press "Edit" on your question and post your code there

Comment: Thanks I understant finally the error.